# How do you say the idiom "by day .. by night"

Tags: idiom

how do you say in German something like the expression "worker by day, superhero by night": is it:

- am Tag / bei Nacht
- bei Tag / bei Nacht ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @SwissCodeMen gave you some correct translations, in this context, I think your suggestions are already the best ones. It's [idiomatic](https://www.br.de/nachrichten/kultur/lux-krieger-des-lichts-wenn-der-gemuesehaendler-batman-spielt,QfZC45R) [to](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/erzieher-bei-tag-superheld-bei-nacht-notizbuch-120-seiten-punktraster--erzieher--pdagoge-german-edition/26049939/#isbn=1661705669) [say](https://www.vertical-life.info/en/indoor/kletterhalle-wien/climbs/876c94e7386d192cd5e95ff9bf2a7fb9).

> Arbeiter **bei Tag**, Superheld **bei Nacht**.

[or](https://blog.emsisoft.com/de/34773/die-geschichte-eines-superschurken-30-jahre-ransomware/) [this](https://www.shirtee.com/de/hoodies-superheld-bei/)

> Arbeiter **am Tag[e]**, Superheld **bei Nacht**.

Answer (score 2):

> Office worker **by day** and superhero **by night**

To translate this sentence/motto in german, it would look like this: 
”Büroangestellte am Tag und Superhelden in der Nacht.” (-> related to work.)

But you can also say ”durch den Tag” instead of ”am Tag” for the translation **by day**. The same is also ”tagsüber”.

For **by night** you can also say ”durch die Nacht”, ”in der Nacht” or ”während der Nacht”. Another example is: **They work at night**, in german you can say: ”Sie arbeiten nachts” and this means the same like **by night**.

Comment: So all variants are correct, and if I use any of these, the desired idiom would be understood. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Why do you use plural for the translation, when then original text uses singular?

Comment: To show the questioner various possibilities ...

Comment: why do you extend something that should be the quote (office) and capslock it? I personally read capslock with a screaming voice. the > highlights it a bit (not as much as  the yellow from old times)

Comment: The questioner used an excerpt from this sentence (which I wrote, now lowercase...). And because of that, I took the whole sentence to make it easier to understand ...

Answer (score 2):

Meine Version: ***Tagsüber** einfacher Arbeiter - **nachts** ein Superheld.*